# foreach contents getting skipped

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got an ASP.NET MVC4 view that looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Bloom.Models.GalleryImageVM>
<div id="gallery">
    @foreach (var img in Model)
    {
        <a href="#" id="@img.Title">
            <img src="@img.URL" />
        </a>
    }
</div>
```

GalleryImageVM is an object with two string properties:

```
public class GalleryImageVM
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Data is definitely getting populated since Model has the expected values in it. However, nothing inside the foreach gets hit. A breakpoint won't get hit, and if I step through it, the execution will touch each of the expected parts of the foreach definition, but won't enter the curly braces.

What am I missing?

**Update:** Just to clarify, Model most definitely has data in it, and stepping through the code shows that both Model and img have the expected result.

Comment: Where are you using this view? Is `<a href....` is getting rendered?

Comment: Are you actually passing the model to the view?

Comment: @Satpal, no as I said, nothing inside the curly braces is getting touched. Neither stepping through the code or setting a break point works either.

Comment: @Yellowfog, Yes, I also mention in the question that Model definitely has the expected values, as does img.

Comment: Is this a copy and paste or your code or a retype / summarized?  I'm wondering if your actual code has a `;` at the end of the `foreach` line, since `img` is getting a value.

Comment: @cadrell0: Yeah, I copied and pasted straight from the view.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to see it is to **debug** the output...

how about if you do things like:

```
<div id="gallery">
    @if(Model.Count() == 0)
    {
       <h2>Nothing to see here</h2>
    }
    else 
    {
        foreach (var img in Model)
        {
          <a href="#" id="@img.Title">
            <img src="@img.URL" />
          </a>
        }
    }
</div>
```

or as simple as

```
<div id="gallery" class="gallery-@Model.Count()">
    @foreach (var img in Model)
    {
        <a href="#" id="@img.Title">
            <img src="@img.URL" />
        </a>
    }
</div>
```

and you can even hit "Debug" and add a **breakpoint** before the `return View(model)` and see the contents of your model before it sends the data to the view.

[image]